# preg_replace href anchor with anchor text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how can i replace all the anchors with each anchor text . my code is

```
$body='<p>The man was <a href="http://www.example.com/video/">dancing like a little boy</a> while all kids were watching ... </p>';
```

i want the result to be :

```
<p>The man was dancing like a little boy while all kids were watching ... </p>
```

i used :

```
$body= preg_replace('#<a href="https?://(?:.+\.)?ok.co.*?>.*?</a>#i', '$1', $body);
```

and result is :

```
<p>The man was while all kids were watching ... </p>
```

Comment: When should the ellipsis ... appear? After a certain no. of words or characters?

Comment: body  string contains many anchors and i want to loop them all checking exactly 'www.example.com' and not the sub-domains, replacing each anchor with its text . thanks

Comment: @khalil Try below Answer put by me. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go the regex path instead of the [plethora of libraries available for you to actually reliably parse a DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$body='<p>The man was <a href="http://www.example.com/video/">dancing like a little boy</a> while all kids were watching ... </p>';

    echo preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $body);
```

Comment: thanks this works to replace all anchors but sorry i should mentioned that i dont want to replace sub domains in href, it should match exactly if href contains 'www.example.com' and not to replace any other domain or sub-domain

Comment: Could you explain with example how you want to see?

Answer (score 2):

Without regexes.....

```
<?php

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML('<p>The man was <a href="http://www.example.com/video/">dancing like a little boy</a> while all kids were watching ... </p>');
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
foreach($x->query('//a') as $anchor){
    $url = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $domain = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
    if($domain == 'www.example.com'){
        $anchor->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($anchor->textContent),$anchor);
    }
}

function get_inner_html( $node ) {
    $innerHTML= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child );
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
echo get_inner_html($x->query('//body')[0]);
```

Comment: Why using XPath when `$d->getElementsByTagName('a')` does the same. However XPath may be interesting if you register a function to check the domain name and if you select only links nodes that have this domain in your query: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php

Comment: You could use that as well for sure, I just needed a quick non-regex example where `XPath` is my default go-to. You don't strictly need a PHP function for the href though: `//a[starts-with(@href,'http://www.example.com')]` might work for the OP as well, depending on whether alternatives like `https://www.example.com` or `//www.example.com` are expected or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) here.

> **strip_tags** - Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string
>
> **htmlspecialchars** - Convert special characters to HTML entities

**Step 1:** Use *strip_tags()* to strip all tags except the `<p>` tag.

**Step 2:** Since we need to obtain the string along with the HTML tags, we need to use *htmlspecialchars()*.

```
echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($body, '<p>'));
```

When there's already an in-built PHP function, I think it's better and more compact to use that instead of using `preg_replace`

Comment: sorry i should mentioned that i dont want to replace sub domains in href, it should match exactly if href contains 'www.example.com' and not to replace any other domain or sub-domain

Answer (score 1):

can use this code:

> **regex :** `/< a.*?>|<a.*?>|<\/a>/g`

```
$body='<p>The man was <a href="http://www.example.com/video/">dancing like a little boy</a> while all kids were watching ... </p>';

echo preg_replace('/< a.*?>|<a.*?>|<\/a>/', ' ', $body);
```

> test and show example match word: https://regex101.com/r/mgYjoB/1

Comment: There shouldn't be any space before a valid tag name, hence `< a` is not valid. Also you could shorten your regex to this **`<\/?a\b[^<>]*>`**